# Internet Explorer XHR Upload Progress Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I using `xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {});` to calculate upload speed, however IE 11 (and probably older) is returning unusable information.

IE is sending an event on every 131072 bytes sent, but the timing is incorrect. Sometimes the event will be sent once a millisecond, sometimes it will be sent in a 2 thousandths of a MS (a bunch being sent really quickly.) This is messing up my speed because it makes it appear that the data is really quickly since most of the events are being send in a thousandth MS while some are taking over a MS.

Is there any way around this?